# cassandra long latency for query if many rows in result

Tags: performance, cassandra, latency

exp:  table schema:

```
Create Table tbl { 
   key int, 
   seq  int, 
   name text, 
   Primary key(key, seq) };
```

For each key, there are multiple rows(1000K suppose); 
Suppose I want to query content for a specific key, My query is:

```
select * from tbl where key = 'key1'
```

(actually I use the cpp driver in program, and use the paging interface)

Result contains 1000k rows, and it costs about 10s for this query. 
I think data for each query is stored together on disk, so it should be very fast to return.

Why it costs so long time?
  Is there any way to optimize???

Comment: use 1st method else u have to write query 10 times.
and  if you use seq as condition u are restricting rows.
what is your requirement?

Comment: 1000 rows?  or 1000K rows?  K == 1000, so 1000K == 1000x1000 == 1 million?

Answer (score 0):

> Why it costs so long time?

There are almost 1000K=1000,000=**1M** rows returned from your query. That's why it costs too long time.

> Is there any way to optimize???

**Yes!!** there are.

Try using **`limit`** and **pivoting/pagination** in the query.

From table definition, it seems that you have a clustering key `seq` you can easily use this `seq` value to optimize your query. Assuming clustering key(`seq`) has default ascending order. Changed your query to:

`select * from tbl where key = 'key1' and seq > [pivot] limit 100`

replace `[pivot]` with the last value of your result set. for the first query use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as `[pivot]`.

For example:

`select * from tbl where key = 'key1' and seq > -100 limit 100`

Comment: I already use the pagination API in cpp-driver when query. And, the limit is another way of pagination, right?